# Autowire service to use inside bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, autowired

Is it possible to somehow autowire a service and use it inside another bean?
I have this:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/api/wallet/slot/thunderkick/**") //intercept calls to
                                   .uri("http://mrq-wallet-forwarder.mircloud.host/") //forward to
                               .id("thunderkickModule"))
                  .build();
}
```

but I need that and this doesnt seem to be the right way to do it:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, 
                ***@Autowired val discoveryService: AccountDiscoveryService***) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/api/wallet/slot/thunderkick/**") //intercept calls to
                               .uri(discoveryService.getHost()) //forward to
                               .id("thunderkickModule"))
                  .build();
}
```

Any recommendations would be really helpful and appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do it.
Try it like this:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, 
                      @Autowired AccountDiscoveryService discoveryService) {
    //Objects.requiredNotNull(discoveryService); //null check if discoveryService can be null
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/api/wallet/slot/thunderkick/**") //intercept calls 
                               .uri(discoveryService.getHost()) //forward to
                               .id("thunderkickModule"))
                  .build();
}
```

Also you can move String values to property file. It is better way for configuration classes.